# Laptop detects HDMI connection but won't display anything

Tags: windows-7, hdmi, tv

I have an old HP laptop running Windows 7. When I connect my TV with an HDMI connector I can see the second screen show up on the windows display settings. It even recognizes the brand and size of the TV. I can also see the "no signal" message on the TV disappear for a few seconds and then come back.
Any settings I choose at this point won't make anything show on the TV. I tried splitting the display, duplicating, or just using just the TV screen.

What else could I try?

Comment: What option are you trying to view the output on the TV to? Some TVs have a PC (DSUB) and HDMI (in your case) individually on different channels.

Comment: I would test by insuring the "refresh rate" is at 60, then drop the resolution way down, and work up.  Also some TVs dont like some resolutions. Feed it something close to a 720res. Then play with it a bit.  Had one 720 capable tv it would only work with 3-4 resolutions. It was a cheap tv, but once I found a resolution it was happy with, it worked ok.

Answer (score 0):

While I hate to not give you an exact response I can give you a link. The process is quite lengthy and I don't feel like typing it out. I'd recommend going [here](http://www.microsoft.com/athome/organization/twomonitors.aspx#fbid=tnCWKWhgfXS) however and checking out what windows has to say. They have trouble shooting tips and also gives you step by step instructions. Good luck!

Comment: Griffin The link just specifies the steps for setting it up. I already did all that.  
I have other laptops that could easily connect to the same TV, and I'm very familiar with the process. This one "behaves" as if it is connecting, but there is nothing displayed on the TV. Except for a brief moment when I connect the HDMI cable, it keeps saying "no signal"

Comment: @RonHarlev I am aware of that however I thought you would be more interested in their trouble shooting processes.